# TranslateModule Configuration Not Working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module, ngx-translate

I have created the following file to isolate `ngx-translate` configuration:

```js
import {
  Http
} from '@angular/http';
import {
  TranslateHttpLoader
} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {
  TranslateLoader,
  TranslateModuleConfig
} from '@ngx-translate/core';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

export function translateModuleConfig(): TranslateModuleConfig {
  return {
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
      deps: [Http]
    }
  };
}
```

Then I'm simply using the following inside my app module `imports` section:

`TranslateModule.forRoot(translateModuleConfig)`

But it's not actually working anymore, unlike when I had the configuration directly inline instead of the function. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: what dou mean it doesnt work ? any outputs , errors would help for sure !

Comment: Translated text just does not appear, no errors whatsoever!
And sure enough, as soon as I copy the object `{ loader: ... }` back into the app module directly instead of the function `translateModuleConfig`, translations appear again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your function to this:

```
export function translateModuleConfig() {
  return {
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
      deps: [Http]
    }
  };
}
```

and then in your `app` modules do this:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot(translateModuleConfig());
```